# How to Add Font & Font size in Ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I want to Add Some Font And Font Size In Ck-editor Same Font As My Website. 
So Please Tell me How to Add my Costume Font in Ck editor?

Answer (score 1):

To control the list of available fonts in the **Font** dropdown list, use the `config.font_names` setting (documentation [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-font_names)).

To control the list of available font sizes in the **Size** dropdown list, use the `config.fontSize_sizes` setting (documentation [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-fontSize_sizes)).

You can also control the list of styles in the **Styles** dropdown list (and add your own styles) by editing the `styles.js` file, located in ckeditor's root folder.